# Getting the exposed form to show up

Tags: blocks, views

I'm trying to get the exposed form to show up for one of my views, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've got filters exposed in the "Filter Criteria" section, the "Exposed Form In Block" section is set to "Yes", and the block itself has been activated and placed into one of the sidebars, but its still not showing up.

Am I forgetting to do something here?

Edit: Forgot to add that I'm using Drupal 7

Edit 2: Found a post that says to turn Ajax on to get the form to display, but that doesn't work either.

Edit 3: So turning off the "Exposed Form in Block" option gets the filters to display, but for theming purposes I really need this stuff in a block.

Comment: Check the block visibility, and if the exposed block is
made to display on the page already than you may try checking the region to which you have assigned your block is rendered or not. It should have nothing to do with the ajax enabling/disabling.

Comment: Yup, checked both. The block is set up to display on all pages, and the region does exist. I've even moved the block around to other regions but it doesn't seem to want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Are you filtering your block to only display on certain pages? It could be that the block is not displaying because of your filtering constraints.

Another thing to check is to make sure the region you have placed the block in exists on that particular page.

Answer (score 0):

Check Block is rendering correctly in the region you want to show.
Try to put any other block in that region and see is it visible or not.